# Reverse a Map with results in a Set

Tags: java

I am attempting to get a Map to reverse the keys and values, then combine the new values into a Set.

For example,

```
Map<String, String> favoriteColors = new HashMap<String, String>();
    favoriteColors.put("Jacob", "Red");
    favoriteColors.put("Mason", "Blue");
    favoriteColors.put("Ethan", "Green");
    favoriteColors.put("William", "Red"); reverseMapping(favoriteColors).entrySet()`
```

Would return

Red=(Jacob, William), Blue=(Mason), Green=(Ethan)

I'm not even really sure where to start with this.

I've thought about iterating through the original Map, but I can't think of a way to create new, unique Sets for every different color.

Comment: start by defining final data structure

Comment: `HashSet` and `TreeSet` don't preserve insertion order, were you planning on using [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)?

Comment: Check out guava's multimap

Comment: One approach would be to provide both mappings when you insert an item (Note: this will double the space complexity of your algorithm). So when you insert the key `'jacob'` with the value `'red'`, you would also insert the key `'red'` with the value `'jacob'` (This would also change your map definition to `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in plain Java:

```
    private Map<String, Set<String>> reverseMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        Collection<String> values = map.values();
        Iterator<String> it = values.iterator();
        Map<String, Set<String>> reverseMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            String val = it.next();
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            reverseMap.put(val, set);
        }

        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        for (String key:keys) {
            String val = map.get(key);
            Set<String> set = reverseMap.get(val);
            set.add(key);
        }
        return reverseMap;
    }
```

The following code:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("John", "Red");
    map.put("Pepe", "Blue");
    map.put("Myself", "Red");

    Map<String, Set<String>> out = reverseMap(map);
    System.out.println(out);
```

Produces:

```
{Blue=[Pepe], Red=[John, Myself]}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed. This is for an assignment that wouldn't have the freedom to import Guava. Thank you again!

Comment: You don't really need a Set here, the uniqueness is already enforced by the fact the the names are also keys in a Map.

Answer (score 3):

As *Bohemian* mentionned, I'd recommend you to use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

For example:

```
    final Map<String, String> favoriteColors = new HashMap<>();
    favoriteColors.put("Jacob", "Red");
    favoriteColors.put("Mason", "Blue");
    favoriteColors.put("Ethan", "Green");
    favoriteColors.put("William", "Red");

    final Multimap<String, String> map = Multimaps.forMap(favoriteColors);
    final Multimap<String, String> inverted = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    Multimaps.invertFrom(map, inverted);

    System.out.println(inverted);
```

Output:

```
{Blue=[Mason], Red=[William, Jacob], Green=[Ethan]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stream-based approach using [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) to perform the grouping:

```java
private static <K, V> Map<V, Set<K>> reverseMapping(Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Collectors.toSet())));
}
```